# Режим просмотра ресурса меню

Tags: android, menu, android-resources

В моем проекте есть ресурс для меню. Просматривать этот ресурс можно в design-режиме, это здорово. Но в этом режиме меню представлено так, будто оно помещено в ActonBar/Toolbar. Допустим, я хочу использовать это меню в NavigationLayout, где оно, разумеется, будет выглядеть немного иначе. Есть ли способ смотреть на меню в design-режиме так, чтобы оно показывалось, будто помещено в NavigationLayout?

Answer (score 4):

Находим `DrawerLayout` прикручиваем ему тулсу `tools:openDrawer="start"`, которая покажет его в развернутом виде в preview (можно left), ну это уже чисто RTL. Пример:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
```

После нужно в xml через app scheme, добавить меню, `app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"` выглядит это примерно так:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

После этого экран в Preview будет выглядеть примерно так:
Screen c Preview
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну это не сосем то, что я искал. Мы смотрим на активити, в которой есть NavigationView, в котором есть menu. А чтоб сразу в ресурсе самого меню?